# How to get asp generated ID?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, label

This code

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_select" ClientIDMode="Static" type="checkbox" runat="server" />
```

generate this

```
<input id="CheckBox_select" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView_reminderList$ctl03$CheckBox_select">
```

How can I get  ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView_reminderList$ctl03$CheckBox_select such that I could use it like

```
<label for="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView_reminderList$ctl03$CheckBox_select"></label>
```

The checkbox is in gridview so I can't access it that easily

Comment: And you get it by typing `<label for="<%=CheckBox_select.ClientID%>" ...`

Comment: Your checkbox is inside a gridview control?Do you want to access it using javascript or jQuery?

Comment: @DenisWessels My checkbox is on gridview. I want to access it inside the gridview

Comment: If you give property `Text` for an `asp: CheckBox`, it automatically gets rendered as `label for=`.